# How to create a React input field for pasting mathematical content from MS Word while preserving format?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, math, equation

I want to make an input field Question in my reactjs application in which I want to paste mathematical content from MS word, but of same format like this :

[Math Question with Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgb6M.png)

So the user can simply copy from word and paste to the input field in a form and then the form can be previewed with the same format as it's in the word document.

I tried this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Input } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import MathJax from "react-mathjax2";
import "./styles.css";

const sampleEquation1 = "U = 1/(R_(si) + sum_(i=1)^n(s_n/lambda_n) + R_(se))";
const sampleEquation2 = "c = a^2 + b^2";
const sampleEquation3 =
  "f(a) = 1/(R_(si) + sum_(i=1)^n(s_n/lambda_n) + R_(se))";

export default function App() {
  const [equation, setEquation] = useState(sampleEquation1);

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ padding: 16 }}>
      <Form
        form={form}
        onValuesChange={(changedValue) => {
          console.log('changedValue',changedValue)
          setEquation(changedValue.equation);
        }}
      >
        <Form.Item name="equation" initialValue={equation}>
          <Input.TextArea />
        </Form.Item>
        <div>Preview:</div>
        <div>
          <MathJax.Context input="ascii">
            <div>
             <p><MathJax.Node>{equation}</MathJax.Node></p>
            </div>
          </MathJax.Context>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is working fine with the equation, but when I add any simple text, it gives wrong result
[copied question from word to react input] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHDN.png)